# Add Key to Entity Framework model to satisfy need keys?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to scaffold a new API controller using NetCore Entity Framework. However, I am getting this error: "cannot be added because it targets the keless entity type RobotResponses"

In the database, RobotResponses is a table with no primary key. But it has two columns named SessionId and HumanId that are both foreign keys, and have an Index like this:
uq_RobotResponses_sessionId_humanId

Now, in my code, should I make both properties keys like this?

```
[Key]   
public long SessionId { get; set; }
[Key]
public long HumanId { get; set; }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you’re looking for is something called Composite Keys. You configure it in the fluent api like this: 
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/haskey-method